# Issues with my javafx game

Tags: java, javafx, logic

I am having two issues right now. The biggest issue is the game pieces in the top left corner are not moving but the bottom right ones are. The next problem is I want the pieces to be able to snap into place on the selected tile. Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

```
 package test;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Board extends Application {


Pane player1 = new Pane();
Pane player2 = new Pane();
TilePane tp = new TilePane();
final int TILE_SIZE = 50;
int[][] logic = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2}};


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

public void start(Stage ps) {

    StackPane sp = new StackPane();

    setTile();  
    setPlayer1Pieces();
    setPlayer2Pieces();


    sp.getChildren().addAll(tp, player1, player2);
    Scene s = new Scene(sp, 390, 390);

    ps.setScene(s);
    ps.setTitle("PP2 Halma Project");
    ps.setResizable(false);
    ps.show();
}

public void setTile() {
    final int size = 8;

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {

        if (k == 0 || k % 2 == 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0) {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    r.setWidth(50);
                    r.setHeight(50);
                    r.setFill(Color.web("lemonchiffon"));
                    tp.getChildren().add(r);
                }

                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    r.setWidth(50);
                    r.setHeight(50);
                    r.setFill(Color.web("brown"));
                    tp.getChildren().add(r);
                }
            }
        }

        if (k % 2 == 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0) {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    r.setWidth(50);
                    r.setHeight(50);
                    r.setFill(Color.web("brown"));
                    tp.getChildren().add(r);
                }

                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    r.setWidth(50);
                    r.setHeight(50);
                    r.setFill(Color.web("lemonchiffon"));
                    tp.getChildren().add(r);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setPlayer2Pieces() {
    int count = 4;

    do {
        for (int i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {

                if (count == 4) {
                    Circle c = new Circle();
                    c.setRadius(20);
                    c.setCenterX(375);
                    c.setCenterY(225);
                    c.setFill(Color.web("#B7B8B6"));
                    c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                        c.setCenterX(e.getSceneX());
                        c.setCenterY(e.getSceneY());
                    });

                    player2.getChildren().add(c);
                }

                if (count == 3) {
                    for (int x = 375; x > 275; x-= 50) {
                        Circle c = new Circle();
                        c.setRadius(20);
                        c.setCenterX(x);
                        c.setCenterY(275);
                        c.setFill(Color.web("#B7B8B6"));

                        c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                            c.setCenterX(e.getSceneX());
                            c.setCenterY(e.getSceneY());
                        });
                        player2.getChildren().add(c);
                    }
                }

                if (count == 2) {
                    for (int x = 375; x > 225; x-= 50) {
                        Circle c = new Circle();
                        c.setRadius(20);
                        c.setCenterX(x);
                        c.setCenterY(325);
                        c.setFill(Color.web("#B7B8B6"));

                        c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                            c.setCenterX(e.getSceneX());
                            c.setCenterY(e.getSceneY());
                        });
                        player2.getChildren().add(c);
                    }
                }

                if (count == 1) {
                    for (int x = 375; x > 175; x-= 50) {
                        Circle c = new Circle();
                        c.setRadius(20);
                        c.setCenterX(x);
                        c.setCenterY(375);
                        c.setFill(Color.web("#B7B8B6"));

                        c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                            c.setCenterX(e.getSceneX());
                            c.setCenterY(e.getSceneY());
                        });
                        player2.getChildren().add(c);
                    }
                }
                count--;
            }   
        }
    } while (count > 0);
}

public void setPlayer1Pieces() {
    int count = 1;
    do {
        for (int i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

                if (count == 1) {
                    for (int x = 25; x < 200; x += 50) {
                        Circle c = new Circle();
                        c.setRadius(20);
                        c.setCenterX(x);
                        c.setCenterY(25);
                        c.setFill(Color.web("#626D71"));
                        c.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                        c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                            c.setCenterX(e.getSceneX());
                            c.setCenterY(e.getSceneY());
                        });
                        player1.getChildren().add(c);
                    }
                }

                if (count == 2) {
                    for (int x = 25; x < 150; x += 50) {
                        Circle c = new Circle();
                        c.setRadius(20);
                        c.setCenterX(x);
                        c.setCenterY(75);
                        c.setFill(Color.web("#626D71"));
                        c.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                        c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                            c.setCenterX(e.getSceneX());
                            c.setCenterY(e.getSceneY());
                        });
                        player1.getChildren().add(c);
                    }
                }

                if (count == 3) {
                    for (int x = 25; x < 100; x += 50) {
                        Circle c = new Circle();
                        c.setRadius(20);
                        c.setCenterX(x);
                        c.setCenterY(125);
                        c.setFill(Color.web("#626D71"));
                        c.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                        c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                            c.setCenterX(e.getSceneX());
                            c.setCenterY(e.getSceneY());
                        });
                        player1.getChildren().add(c);
                    }
                }

                if (count == 4) {
                    Circle c = new Circle();
                    c.setRadius(20);
                    c.setCenterX(25);
                    c.setCenterY(175);
                    c.setFill(Color.web("#626D71"));
                    c.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                    c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                        c.setCenterX(e.getSceneX());
                        c.setCenterY(e.getSceneY());
                    });
                    player1.getChildren().add(c);
                }
            }
            count ++;
        }
    } while (count < 5);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's generally encouraged to post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It shows that you've taken time to make it easy for us to help you. If you just post 100s of lines of code, you might get lucky and someone will help, but chances are people won't bother to read through the whole thing. I suggest you gut out as much of the code that is not relevant to your problem as possible then edit your question. It may be best to demonstrate one problem first, and create another question for the second.

Comment: You could and should replace your (count == num) if statements with a switch-case statement